# WebResource.axd return Empty response

Tags: asp.net, webresource.axd

Only on my development machine, when I point to a WebResource.axd file, I get an empty response.

```
Sample url: xxx.yyy.com/WebResource.axd?d=[Encrypted quesrystring]&t=[timestamp]
```

It does not happen on Integration server or QA servers. It also works on one of my colleague's machine, but not on another one's machine.

The webresoruce response, when it works returns CSS & JavaScript etc. It returns CSS & JavaScript for Ajax Control Toolkit.

Does anybody know why it would happen?

I have checked the web.config in the Framework folder and the mapping exists under

```
<httpHandlers>
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this bug because my app applies Deflate compression on all text-resources.
After removing compression of all handlers, the problem is solved.